# One-way multi column UNIQUE constraint

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a system in which I am trying to describe event-based interactions between two targets. In our system, an event (interaction) has a "source" and a "target" (basically who [did what] to whom):

```sql
-- tried to remove some of the "noise" from this for the sake of the post:
CREATE TABLE interaction_relationship (
    id integer CONSTRAINT interaction_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    source_id integer CONSTRAINT source_fk NOT NULL REFERENCES entity(id),
    target_id integer CONSTRAINT target_fk NOT NULL REFERENCES entity(id),

    -- CONSTRAINT(s)
    CREATE CONSTRAINT interaction_relationship_deduplication UNIQUE(source_id, target_id)
);
```

Constraint `interaction_relationship_deduplication` is the source of my question:

In our system, a single source can interact with a single target multiple times, but that relationship can only exist once, i.e. if I am a mechanic working on a car, I may see that car multiple times in my shop, but I have only one relationship with that single car:

| id | source_id | target_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 123abc | 456def |
| b | 123abc | 789ghi |

Ideally, this table also represents a unidirectional relationship. `source_id` is always the "owner" of the interaction, i.e. if the car `456def` ran over the mechanic `123abc` there would be another entry in the `interaction_relationship` table:

| id | source_id | target_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123abc | 456def |
| 2 | 123abc | 789ghi |
| 3 | 456def | 123abc |

So, my question: does `UNIQUE` on multiple columns take value order into consideration? Or would the above cause a failure?

Comment: "*tried to remove some of the "noise" from this table*" - are there other columns? Does this table only describe the relationship itself, or does it represent the interactions (events) and includes the "did what"?

Comment: @Bergi I just meant statements like `IF NOT EXISTS`. But the columns are as they are - just the relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does `UNIQUE` on multiple columns take value order into consideration?

Yes. The tuple `(123abc, 456def)` is different from the tuple `(456def, 123abc)`, they may both exist in the table at the same time.

---

That said, you might want to remove the [surrogate `id`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) from the relationship table, there's hardly any use for it. A relation table (as opposed to an entity table, and even there) would do totally fine with a multi-column primary key, which is [naturally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) the combination of source and target.

Comment: Thank you! This is mega helpful. Trying to get back into enterprise-level doing and constantly having to sanity check myself.